# Where am I? (inspired by a classic novel)

Tags: rhyme, knowledge

```
I am the hidden land
Where man may not tread but wildlife can

Here a group in full did travel
By peak twilight, by horse and paddle

The group spoke sin and thus went in
To rule over all within
```

Where am I?

**HINT 1**

> Man may not tread in this place but man is not the only species in this universe

**HINT 2**

> This place is a place of great beauty and serenity

**HINT 3**

> Man may only enter this place if invited in

**Final Hint**

> A fellowship also visit this place at some point in their quest.

Comment: Could it be **Jumanji**, a book and a film as well?

Comment: Nope it's not Jumanji :)

Comment: Well maybe my first guess was correct afterall... Am I on the right way if I say LotR @MasterYoda?

Comment: @Saeïdryl I cant say you are wrong ;)

Comment: @Saeïdryl Think about all of the locations the fellowship visited, take all of the hints into consideration. This may take a little more research on Tolkiens world and all of its languages/inhabitants

Comment: That was a nice LotR riddle, now I want to do a LotR extended edition marathon...

Comment: @Saeïdryl Thank you. Yeah I have the FOTR soundtrack blasting at my desk in work :)

Comment: @MasterYoda Please do not put the answer inside the question. If you like to add information, you can comment on the accepted answer or self answer if you feel that no answer fits.

Comment: @wl The question has already been answered by Sanea. I posted the answer within spoiler tags so as to obscure it from anyone who didnt want to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be :

> Lothlorien

I am the hidden land

> Tolkien occasionally referred to Lothlorien as 'the hidden land'

Where man may not tread but wildlife can

> Man, Dwarves, orc etc. are forbidden from entering Lothlorien without the permission of the elves

Here a group in full did travel
By peak twilight, by horse and paddle

> If we look at the history of lothlorien, it was initially settled by Silvan elves of Nandorin descent. Some time later the Sindar elves arrived and enriched the population and culture of Lothlorien

The group spoke sin and thus went in

> This was a play on words, the Sindar elves spoke Sindarin and entered into Lothlorien

To rule over all within

> The Sindar elves enriched lothlorien with Sindar culture, their ruler was the Sindar lord Amdír.

Comment: Correct! Although some of your points are a little off. I will accept your answer and update the question to make the points i was after

Comment: I've read the Silmarillon so long ago, I have the correct answer for the wrong reason because my knowledge of the LoTR universe is fading away :/

Comment: Updated your answer with the points I made in my original edit

Answer (score 2):

Could it be :

> Rivendell

I am the hidden land

> Obviously it's an hidden place

Where man may not tread but wildlife can

> Only elves are allowed here

Here a group in full did travel

> One of the only moment where the fellowship of the ring was all together

By peak twilight, by horse and paddle.

> Men came on horses, hobbits were on paddle once, and dwarves probably by their mountains

The group spoke sin and thus went in

> They were arguing, and gandalf spoke the black language

Comment: Don't be afraid to write another answer instead of editing yours if it's another idea! https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/whats-the-etiquette-for-providing-multiple-answers-to-a-question

Comment: Very close, but there are a couple of other locations the fellowship visited either in whole and in part.

Answer (score 1):

That's (not but close)

> Moria

I am the hidden land

> Moria is an underground mine in the Misty Mountains

Where man may not tread but wildlife can

> Dwarves' kingdom

Here a group in full did travel
By peak twilight, by horse and paddle

> The fellowship of the ring came by paddle at night

The group spoke sin and thus went in

> "Speak friend and enter"

To rule over all within

> Ash nazg durbatulûk, ash nazg gimbatul,
>  Ash nazg thrakatulûk agh burzum-ishi krimpatul.

Comment: Next time I'll listen to myself and answer with my first guess ! ("The group spoke sin and thus went in" was the biggest hint)

Comment: I feel so bad having to write this, you are so close! Think about that line carefully, the group spoke sin and thus went in. Moria is a great guess though

Comment: Argh! I was 95% sure about that! I'm heartbroken... Indeed "spoke sin" can't really fit with "friend"...

Comment: You got this ;)

Comment: Perhaps "The group spoke sin" is short for "The group spoke Sindarin", which does fit with saying "friend" in Elvish.

Comment: I don't think so, Master Yoda already said that wasn't the answer

Comment: @J.Siebeneichler That was a great suggestion, very close

Answer (score 0):

Possible partial answer - Going off of memory so I hope I'm remembering the book correctly.

> You are in Narnia (from the series Chronicles of Narnia)

I am the hidden land
Where man may not tread but wildlife can

> Narnia is a secret place where "man" does not live.  It is populated by animals and fantasy creatures.

Here a group in full did travel
By peak twilight, by horse and paddle

> The 4 siblings traveled in and around Narnia using various methods - not sure about the twilight reference?

The group spoke sin and thus went in 
To rule over all within

> They had to go into a wardrobe to reach Narnia and eventually became the rulers - from @Saeïdryl in comments: Sin could reference the children swearing to each other before crossing over into Narnia

Comment: Hmm, my initial thought was exactly the same, but not too sure about whether it fits...

Comment: "The group spoke sin" is maybe when they crossed together for the first time? Swearing on each others in the wardrobe? Maybe they were a little too young to swear though... And they are 4 not 3 !

Comment: @Saeïdryl Ah, you're right it was 4!  Updated with your suggestion

Comment: "Peak Twilight" might be a reference to Winter.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, could be

> Earth

I am the hidden land
Where man may not tread but wildlife can

> Adam and Eve were promised to stay in the Garden of Eden
> Not sure if they saw Earth before being sent on

The group spoke sin and thus went in
To rule over all within

> 2 persons is a group
> They were exiled on Earth and now humans rule it

I'll work on the second paragraph later :)

Comment: The Bible is a "classic novel" no ? (: